# How to align these DIVs side by side (fiddle inside)?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've managed to align side by side the DIV containing the image, and the DIV containing the text, side by side, by applying `float:left` to the image DIV.

But when I Include these two DIVs in a parent DIV, and duplicate the parent and try to align the parents side by side by applying `float:left` to the first parent, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<div style="width:350px;min-height: 200px; float:left;">
  <div style="float:left;"><img src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px style="border: 1px solid black;padding:1px;"></div>
  <div style="font-size:15pt;color:red;letter-spacing:-.04em;padding-top:2px;padding-left:135px;">Title</div>
  <div style="font-size:11pt;color:black;letter-spacing:-.02em;margin-top:4px;padding-left:135px;">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.</div>
</div>

<div style="width:350px;min-height: 200px;">
  <div style="float:left;"><img src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px style="border: 1px solid black;padding:1px;"></div>
  <div style="font-size:15pt;color:red;letter-spacing:-.04em;padding-top:2px;padding-left:135px;">Title</div>
  <div style="font-size:11pt;color:black;letter-spacing:-.02em;margin-top:4px;padding-left:135px;">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.</div>
</div>
```

[and fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2tdpH/1/)

I also wonder whether the rest of the code is best practice, such as `padding-left:135px` - would it be better to use relative padding from the image, rather than the parent div? if so, what's the easiest way to change that?

Comment: Your `float:left;` rule is outside of your `style` attribute value, meaning it won't be floating that `div` at all. You'd need to apply the `float` to both `div`s.

Comment: You may have better luck with display:inline-block than with float - I typically treat float as the layout of last resort, it causes more problems than it solves.  Hint: when using display:inline-block, you generally also need vertical-align

Comment: @ajp15243 sorry that was just a typo in my post, it doesn't work as well when inside the style attribute.

Comment: @rockyraw The second sentence of my comment (which is the same as the second part of [Marc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22614088/1883647)) states that you also need to apply the `float` rule to both `div`s.

Comment: thanks, that's working now, I just wonder why I have to apply it to both, while with the Image applying only once was enough?

Comment: @rockyraw See the comments under Marc's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `float:left` outside of the style attribute, try moving that inside the speech marks and applying `float: left` to both parent divs.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work (my float was originally inside, it was just a typo in my post), why do I need to apply it to both parents, while with the image it was enough to apply only to the image?

Comment: The divs have display:block which means they'll want to sit in the theoretical row by themselves. Floating overcomes this.

Comment: @rockyraw The text, on the other hand, is inline content, so a sibling floated element will push around the inline content. Floated elements will not push around sibling block content like a default `div` (the block content will, as Marc says, take up the whole "row").

Answer (score 1):

## [Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2tdpH/2/)

You can simply change your code to the below, giving each `div` a `display:inline-block;` then as long as your browser window is greater than the sum of the two `div` widths, they will display inline, no need for floats:

```
<div style="width:350px;min-height: 200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px style="border: 1px solid black;padding:1px;">
    </div>
    <div style="font-size:15pt;color:red;letter-spacing:-.04em;padding-top:2px;padding-left:135px;">Title</div>
        <div style="font-size:11pt;color:black;letter-spacing:-.02em;margin-top:4px;padding-left:135px;"/>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.</div>
</div>
<div style="width:350px;min-height: 200px;display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px style="border: 1px solid black;padding:1px;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="font-size:15pt;color:red;letter-spacing:-.04em;padding-top:2px;padding-left:135px;">Title</div>
    <div style="font-size:11pt;color:black;letter-spacing:-.02em;margin-top:4px;padding-left:135px;">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.</div>
</div>
```

That said I would strongly recommend you separate your CSS from your HTML in order to make a clear distinction between content and presentation and capture the clear benefits that offers.

Comment: It's worth noting that `display: inline-block` will render any whitespace in between the `inline-block` elements, which will lead to potentially unwanted gaps between them.

Comment: thanks, what's the better practice though?
(I would separate them eventually, this is for testing changes)

Answer (score 1):

You had one of your `float: left` attributes outside of the style tag. Also, you should use CSS classes instead of putting all of your CSS styles inline. It makes your code much neater and prevents a lot of duplicated styling. [Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2tdpH/5/) is an updated Fiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img class="image" src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px />
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img class="image" src="image.jpg" width=120px height=120px />
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    width:350px;
    min-height: 200px;
    float:left;
}
.title {
    font-size:15pt;
    color:red;
    letter-spacing:-.04em;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:135px;
}
.text {
    font-size:11pt;
    color:black;
    letter-spacing:-.02em;
    margin-top:4px;
    padding-left:135px;
}
.image-wrap {
    float: left;
}
.image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:1px;
}
```